# Is it possible to automatically install Flash with Chromium?

Tags: flash, chromium

I'm making an application that will run on a browser. Our employees use Google Chrome as their default browser. To make the application independent of the Google Chrome browser, I would like to use Chromium Browser for the web application. So when they use the application, they use the Chromium Browser which would run in kiosk mode and they use Google Chrome for their web browsing.

There are some computers in our office that do not use Internet connection. Is it possible to bundle Flash with Chromium browser so they don't need to install it separately? The installer from get.adobe.com is a web installer that would require each client to download adobe flash separately.

I tried copying and pasting the `pepflashplayer.dll` file to the Chromium installation but it is still prompting me to download flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the offline installer [from here](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html) and then use simple script to install Chromium and Flash player at once.